# How to split polygons without ArcView?

Tags: polygon, algorithm, area

I'm trying to split polygons into equal areas. While fishnet sort of works; the areas I'm trying to split don't touch; they're national parks. Fishnet spans the whole area, not just the polygons  in question. Ultimately, I'm searching for a method to split polygons into a user-given number of equal area polygons.

I've read everything I can about the Huber methods to do this in ArcView, but without access to that (or experience with it) this isn't the answer for me.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you considered this similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/how-can-i-can-i-divide-a-polygon-into-specific-sizes-using-arcgis

Comment: Are the national parks polygons or multipolygons? How would you like those to be handled?

Comment: I have tried to describe the algorithm in a non-AV centric way (in the link provided by @dassouki).  It will work in any GIS that supports scripting where you can (a) implement a 1D root finding algorithm, (b) clip polygons to rectangles, and (c) compute the area of a polygon.  (A variant replaces (b) by (b') internally buffer polygons by specified amounts.  This will dissect polygons into pseudo-concentric rings of specified area.)

Comment: Thanks all (and Bill specifically). I'll have to think out root finding (slightly over my head) but the rest seems do-able. I don't have the specific polygons yet, but I would likely dissolve them each into a single pg for each park. I'll pursue the Huber method, but I believe fishnet may work as well for my needs. With that, I can set the exact size of the cells I want (total area / x) and then just intersect the net with the parks. Some non-park, but that's not essential. Thanks again; will keep posted.

Comment: @MBarretts Read sections 9.0 - 9.3 of *Numerical Recipes*; this will teach you all you need to know about root finding.  http://www.nr.com/bookreader_chooser.html .  I am curious about how "fishnet works," because as far as I can tell that just coarsely grids your polygons: something has to happen afterwards to effect the splitting.

Comment: @mbarretts, you say what software you don't have, Arcview, but you don't say what you *do* have. Also do you mean each split poly has to have the identical area , as in numerically identical # of sq km's for each feature? Because fishnet will not do that, some fishnet squares will be entirely within the parent poly, and others will only partially overlap.

Comment: No trivial mathmatics I think, but into the blue, Constrainted triangulation will of the polygon with a given areal size of the triangles will solve the problem?