# Create perimeter from given area

Tags: polygon

I need to develop a web-based application to manage areas inside a bigger area.

I already have the initial perimeter, and it has irregular borders like that:

[image: Map1].

I will need to tell the app to create a perimeter based only in a given area.

```
createPerimeter(1000); // create perimeter with 1000m2
```

That should create a perimeter with 1000m2 adjacent to the border and to any other existing area.

[image: Map2].

And so on. The above method should create adjacent areas until the end of the container area

[image: Map3].

I'm looking for a solution regardless the language or platform, directions to how to start it.
I believe POSTGIS has many functions that could help me, but I have not found a solution so far.

Regards.

Comment: One solution, which can be iterated to achieve what you want, is described at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/how-to-divide-a-polygon-into-specific-sizes-using-arcgis/5302#5302 in a platform-independent way. It splits your polygon into two pieces whose common boundary lies along a *single* line.  It can be re-applied to those pieces to create as many sub-regions of specified area as you like. (Your illustrations show a more complicated construction, but you do not provide any description or criteria for reproducing it.)

Comment: In ArcGIS, couldn't you create a fishnet grid and then intersect it with the polygon (feature to polygon)?

Comment: can you clarify if you mean perimeter (the line around the area, measured in m) or the area (measured in m2)?

Comment: The links to these maps have rotted; consequently, the question is unintelligible.