# Split polygon by area using ArcGIS for Desktop (or QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, splitting

I'm interested to split a larger, irregular polygon into smaller ones. I know the area of the resulting polygon, and I know that the line I want to split it by should be parallel to one of the sides of the original polygon (line AB in the image below).

[image: Ecample of what I want to do]

I'm also curious if i can do this in one go. For example I have the big polygon (of 2400 sqm for example), and I know I want to split it as follows: (Division 1: 200 sqm, next one 140 sqm, next one 100 sqm, and so on) resulting in 10 new polygons of unequal area, but all of them having edges parallel to side AB of the original polygon.

I work in ArcMap 10.1, but I can use QGIS 2.4 as well if there is some plugin that might help me.

Comment: Related/duplicates: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122193/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/

Comment: Yes!! See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/how-to-divide-a-polygon-into-specific-sizes-using-arcgis/127579#127579   where there is a ready-made solution for it..