# Finding tool to divide polygon into specific areas using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, polygon-creation

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 and am trying to divide a polygon into several smaller polygons based on a percentage.

I have found a theoretical answer [Dividing polygon into specific sizes using ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/how-to-divide-a-polygon-into-specific-sizes-using-arcgis)

I am trying to find the tool (code) described by the user whuber or something similar, but all links found on google seem to be dead.

The suggested commercial tool is not an option for me.

Is there a working link to the code I am trying to find or some other tool that would do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface:

[image]
[image]

Script to divide polygon into 2 single part polygons, using field fraction (0..1):

```
## split polygons

import arcpy, traceback, os, sys
gr=(math.sqrt(5)-1)/2

try:
    def showPyMessage():
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)
    #golden section to find minimum
    def gss(a,b,tol):
        c=b-gr*(b-a)
        d=a+gr*(b-a)
        fc=f(c);fd=f(d)
        while abs(c-d)>tol:
            if fc<fd:
                b,d,fd=d,c,fc
                c=b-gr*(b-a)
                fc=f(c)
            else:
                a,c,fc=c,d,fd
                d=a+gr*(b-a)
                fd=f(d)
        return (b+a)/2
    def f(z):
        global two,fraction
        theP=outline.positionAlongLine (z).firstPoint
        splitter=arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([point,theP]),SR)
        try: two=pgon.cut(splitter)
        except: return 1
        intR=abs(two[0].area/pgon.area-fraction)
        return intR

    # mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    # layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    outputLR=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    pgonLR=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    fld=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
    desc=arcpy.Describe(pgonLR)
    SR = desc.spatialReference


    curT = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputLR,"Shape@")

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pgonLR,("Shape@",fld)) as cursor:
        m=0
        for row in cursor:
            m+=1
            arcpy.AddMessage(m)
            pgon=row[0]
            fraction=row[1]
            outline=pgon.boundary();L=outline.length
            for j in range(100):
                point=outline.positionAlongLine (L*j/100).firstPoint
                chainage=gss(0.01,L,0.001)
                doit=f(chainage)
                if two[0].partCount==1 and two[1].partCount==1:
                    for item in two:
                        curT.insertRow((item,))
                    break
except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

Result sample after 2 runs:

[image]